# UML of use case diagram correct? Extension or generalization?

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case-diagram

I have been trying to understand it but I couldn't. Can someone explain this shortly? Is there some problem with this UML diagram? If there is, where?

[image]

I thought that instead of extending arrows there might be a generalization for the pic, video, tag names, and feeling use cases. And I think that included arrows should have been dashed. Are these true? Thank you already.

Comment: Hello abc. If you are satisfied with one of the answers, please check it as "accepted". Otherwise, please let us know what you are still missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can not understand this since it is absolute nonsense. This is some semi-activity diagram. A use case is about actor goals, not how to do something. Please give the author of that a heavy kick in the rear. Or if you not that rude as myself (being a pacifist with empasis on fist - haha) just encourage them otherwise to start learning about use cases.

As always I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about use cases.

Comment: I agree in principle. I just disagree about the violence recommended against a poor UML author who didn't get the luck of reading your books ;-)  What about "and give the author of that a heavy encouragement to read ... and therewith acquire basic understanding of what a use case is in reality" ?

Comment: @Christophe Probably. But I'm a rude guy. Btw. they are not my books and I don't know any of the authors. I just recommend that book since it's just what should be taught.

Comment: @qwerty_so even if I disagree with your choices about fisting or punching someone XD thank you for your advice.

Comment: Honestly, I'never have beaten anyone. Except in the Dojo. And even there never hard.

Comment: I'm getting more and more convinced that the concept of Use Cases is simply too difficult to understand. If only a small subset of the audience correctly understand and can use use cases, maybe the concept of use cases itself is flawed. I'm finding myself less and less inclined to propose use case modelling; mainly because nobody gets it right; and it's a constant battle against functional decomposition.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Me too. But I DO remember how hard it was for me to understand it. I think that the whole education is towards detailing things and not about getting a context. That's changing now, but (at least myself) seeing that come to some maturity is only a dream. So the only thing to do is: repeat, repeat, repeat.

Comment: @GeertBellekens indeed, for years I was myself mislead by number of tutorials & books about UC.  The early description by Jacobson himself was misleading, since scenarios of interactions and reuse, inevitably lead to functional decomposition.  It's only after having read Lockwood & Constantine's article about essential use-cases that I understood the abstraction power of goal oriented design. In my view, the "Use Case 2.0" really helps to get it right. Unfortunately, there's a lot of inertia&prejudice: people continue to refer to the wrong ATM articles or burn UC in favour of flat stories...

Answer (score 1):

The following aspects of the diagram violate the UML specifications:

1. The boundary box shall represent a system (e.g. Facebook), not a function (Add Status).
2. Keywords include and extend shall be written in guillemets: «include», «extend».
3. The «include» arrows shall be dashed.
4. The «include» arrows shall have open arrow-heads.

To apply the use case technique in a project, the team shall agree on a specific methodology and/or philosophy. UML doesn't offer this, it is just a language (despite some definitions in the UML specification that point in a certain direction). Therefore, I will not give my opinion on whether this is a proper way of use case modeling.

With regard to generalization versus extension: both are possible in this case. If "Add Status" would mean: add pic *or* add video *or* etc., then a generalization would be more appropriate. The extension suggests that "Add Status" means: add pic *and/or* video *and/or* etc. In other words, each extending use case extends the original with additional capabilities.

Comment: No, no, no. The above UC does not contain a single UC but only functions. In that respect you can **not** apply any include/extend! We could only talk about this if there is a basic acknowledgement on what a use case is. I agree with the first 4 statements, but they mean nothing to the above diagram since it is meaningless. Please remove the last paragraph.

Comment: @qwerty_so,  Why do you think "Add status" cannot be a user's goal?

Comment: Because it's simply too primitive. It's definitely a function within some activity. Look at the other bubbles. Where would you find anything that could be a goal? Just like _login_ is no goal. And also look at the lane (misused as boundary) which entitles another function. This is wrong from A to Z.

Comment: @qwerty_so The problem with "primitive" is that it is very difficult to define objectively.   Intuitively it's simple as shown [here on wikipedia (based on Cockburn)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cockburnstyle_use_cases.svg). But the devil is in the detail: why should "store material" not be a user goal but check-in material yes?  I think this is why the UML specs are very permissive (not to speak of the need to protect the interest of industries that invested in millions of UC diagrams based on functional decomposition...)

Comment: @Christophe Whether or not _Add status_ would be a user goal can be put aside. A simple look at this whole diagram above shows that it's not about user goals but functions. It's like one comes with a ship for maintenance and you get offered exchange of break fluid.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl "Add status" is not a user goal in the sense that it does say what action a user can perform in a system or how to do it, but not what the user want to achieve.  Nobody wakes up in the morning thinking "I want to add a status".  People would rather think about "Sharing some news".  Abstracting the goal from the way this goal is implemented can imho lead to more comprehensive solutions, innovation, and more robust design. But I agree with you, the difference is sometimes difficult to define.

Comment: @qwerty_so on this point I fully agree with you !! The diagram does not offer useful insights: it's more a kind of mind mapping to not forget about some elements, rather than a useful model that shares some well structured ideas.

Comment: By the way,  if Facebook'd have engineered its use-case in this way,  the I'd no longer be surprised why my feed is not chronological anymore and why it now only spreads fake news and nothing interesting anymore... ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so, Christophe, I think we agree that the quality of the diagram is poor. We have slightly different opinions about the freedom our colleagues have in using their own use case modeling conventions and still call it UML-compliant. Personally, I am quite mild and tend to give them the benefit of the doubt.